# how to donwload and save several files with nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need make to program in nodejs which take lists files of another website and save in my machine.

for example:

```js
function saveLocalFiles(files) {
    for (var i in files) {
        var file = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, "media/" + files[i].FILE));
        console.log(URL + files[i].FILE);
        http.get(URL + files[i].FILE, function (response) {
            response.pipe(file);
            file.on('finish', function () {
                file.close(() => {
                    console.log("ends ->" + files[i].FILE);
                });

            });
        })
    }
}
```

when I execute it my code does not work with several files. Also, I can't know when it ends to download the files. Can somebody help me?.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

use Promises and try to split your code in two functions :

```
function saveLocalFiles(files) {
    Promise
        .all(files.map(file => saveLocalFile((URL, file.FILE))))
        .then((files) => {
            console.log(files);
        })
 }

function saveLocalFile(URL, FILE) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        var file = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, "media/" + FILE));
        console.log(URL + FILE);
        http.get(URL + FILE, function (response) {
            response.pipe(file);
            file.on('finish', function () {
                file.close(() => {
                    console.log("ends ->" + FILE);
                    resolve(FILE);
                });
            });
        })
    })
}
```